# Dropdowns in strictly typed views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a C# application using MVC 4, LINQ to SQL, and Razor Syntax.

I have created a class that gets the contents of a given row in the db based on a requested id.

I have made a controller that has a get and post handler.  I created a strongly-typed view based on one of the model classes, and everything works great.  Data is retrieved and displayed in the form.  Data can be updated and submitted.

The problem is the dropdowns.  I don't want it to show a textfield for the id.  I want the dropdowns.  I have about five dropdowns, all to be generated from the database.  I've created models to create them.

I can use ViewData or ViewBag to pass in the dropdowns with no problem.  But then, how do I select the selected option when the user loads the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "model" in MVC is supposed to model the *page*, not your data. If you have dropdowns on your page, then you should have a collection of some kind (likely a `List<T>`) on your model that represents the choices, along with another property that represents the selected value. This property will be used to populate the initial value of the dropdown as well as send the selected value back up to the controller.

Comment: I have lists in my model for the dropdown list.  I've got classes that get both the selected value and the dropdown list itself.  My question is, essentially, how do I select the selected item?

Comment: Do you have a property in your model that represents the selected value? If so, `Html.DropDownListFor(...)` should do the job.

Comment: I had not known about .DropDownListFor until now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend avoiding ViewData or ViewBag in favor of a [ViewModel](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx).

A [ViewModel](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx) is essentially a hybrid Model that aggregates all of the data that your View needs into a single entity.  Rather than typing the View to a Model and passing the additional information needed by your View that is not in the Model in ViewData or the ViewBag you have everything you need in the Model that your View is typed to.

In your case the ViewModel might look something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DropDown1 DropDownA { get; set; }
    public DropDown2 DropDownB { get; set; }
    public Model ModelData { get; set; }
}

public class DropDown1
{
    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public List<T> DropDownValues { get; set; }
}

public class DropDown2
{ 
    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public List<T> DropDownValues { get; set; }
}
```

Your View would by typed to `MyViewModel`.  At this point, setting the data source of the drop downs to the drop downs in your ViewModel and setting the SelectedValue would be trivial.